# pyModbus - TCPServer in/out traffic monitor

Tags: python, modbus, tcpserver, modbus-tcp, pymodbus

I am a newbie in python. Sorry if the question may sound silly.

I'm using pyModbus to implement an asynchronous Modbus TCP server on a BeagleBone Black. It works well, I'm able to connect with clients and retrieve values from the registers.

I start the server with:

```
from pymodbus.server.async import StartTcpServer

StartTcpServer(context, identity=identity, address=("0.0.0.0", 502))
```

I'm now trying to implement a monitor of the traffic in and out the server. 
I would need to plot/log all the requests from the client(s) and all the responses from the server.

Is there any way to access the rx/tx buffers?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could enable `logging` as debugging mode for Modbus server as follows:

```
import logging
FORMAT = ('%(asctime)-15s %(threadName)-15s'
          ' %(levelname)-8s %(module)-15s:%(lineno)-8s %(message)s')
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

[Here's the original example.](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/example/asynchronous_server.html)

Comment: Thank you Benyamin but that's way too many information to parse/log. You get an entry for any event happening. I really need just to access the buffers where the in/out messages are stored.